# Pandas to Excel: How to implement similar feature in excel of automatic adjust referenced cell name based on column number

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl

Background:
I have a very large excel file in terms of row number. 
I have a column, say Column A, that is composed of either formulas or numbers or string.
I want to 'copy' Column A to Column C and D:

```
For a row i:
    if 'Bi' is not 0:
       then for column C and D:
           'Ci' or 'Di' = 'Bi'
    else:
        if 'Ai' is not a formula:
            then for column C and D:
               'Ci' or 'Di' = 'Ai'
        else:
            then for column C and D:
                formula in 'Ai' should be copied to 'Ci' or 'Di' but adjusted. E.g. '=A1+A2' should be translated to '=C1+C2' or '=D1+D2'
```

I have half-coded the following sudo-code and hope someone can help me move toward the direction of finishing it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
# add a simple formula
ws["A1"] = 2
ws["A2"] = 3
ws["A3"] = "=1+SUM(A1:A2)"
ws["B1"] = 3
ws["B2"] = 0
ws["B3"] = "=1+SUM(A1:A2)"
wb.save("experiment_openpyxl.xlsx")

data_df = np.array([[2,3],[3,0],['=1+SUM(A1:A2)',0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_df)
print(df)

print(len(df.index))
print(len(df.columns))

column_num_A = 0;
column_num_B = 1;
column_num_C = 2;
column_num_D = 3;
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    if df.loc[i,column_num_B] != 0:
        for j in list[column_num_C,column_num_D]:
            df.loc[i,j] = df.loc[i,column_num_B]
    else:
        #if df.loc[i,column_num_A] is not a formula:
            #for j in list[column_num_C,column_num_D]:
                 #df.loc[i,j] = df.loc[i,column_num_A]
        #else: 
            #for j in list[column_num_C,column_num_D]:
                #df.loc[i,j] = <copy the formula in df.loc[i,column_num_A] but translate A1 etc. to C1 or D1 based on j>
```

Expected output:

```
df original:
                   0  1
    0              2  3
    1              3  0
    2  =1+SUM(A1:A2)  0

df post-processed:
                       0  1            2            3           
        0              2  3            3            3
        1              3  0            3            3 
        2  =1+SUM(A1:A2)  0 =1+SUM(C1:C2) =1+SUM(D1:D2)
```

Comment: You can use the tokeniser in openpyxl to rewrite formulae. The source code for handling shared formulae provides examples of how to do this.

Comment: @ Charlie Clark, Thanks for pointing the direction. I am having a look. Will let you know if I managed to find the solution in this direction